# Querying multiple metrics with Google Analytics API PHP Client

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am just trying to get product sales by number of items sold and the total revenue. I am using Google APIs client library for PHP: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git

I am able to get one metric per product, eg I can list all the products that had a purchase in the last week. Or I can get the total revenue of sales per product in the last week. What I am trying to do is get both at the same time.

So what I tried was...

```
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:itemQuantity,ga:itemRevenue");
```

FYI the rest of the code is pretty much exactly the same as per the https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php#3_setup_the_sample example, I have obviously added in my details and it all works fine if I do just ga:itemQuantity or ga:itemRevenue.

Any documentation I ready says to just comma separate the metrics but it just dies, the whole page doesn't even load so I get no errors etc..

Is what I want to do possible? If so how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't tried using comma separated values, but what you can definitely do is create multiple metrics, like this:

```
$metric1 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$metric1->setExpression("ga:itemQuantity");

$metric2 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$metric2->setExpression("ga:itemRevenue");
```

Then, when you create the request, you can "attach" both of those metrics:

```
// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
...
$request->setMetrics(array($metric1, $metric2));
....

// Follow the samples that you mentioned for the rest
```

That should work, and in the response metric data you should now have an array with the values for both metrics.

Good luck!

Comment: We also need to make sure only 10 array elements allowed in one time for setMetrics()

Answer (score 4):

**Approach 1:-**

Create multiple metrics, like this:

```
// Create the Metrics object.
$metrics = array();
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:itemQuantity");
$sessions->setAlias("ItemQuantity");
$metrics[] = $sessions;

$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:itemRevenue");
$sessions->setAlias("ItemRevenue");
$metrics[] = $sessions;
```

and set Metrics in Google Report Request

```
// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
$request->setMetrics($metrics); // METRIC
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($browser, $country));
```

**Approach 2:-**

```
// Create the Analytics API object
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

// Setup and run the query to Analytics API
$generalstats = $analytics->data_ga->get(
 'ga:XXXXXXXX', // analytics view id
 '2019-05-01', // start date
 '2019-05-31', // end date
 'ga:users,ga:sessions,ga:hits,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounceRate,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:goalConversionRateAll');
```

Simply replace the above parameters (in your case ga:itemQuantity,ga:itemRevenue) and display as you wish

```
// Output all API results
echo '<pre>';
print_r($generalstats);
echo '</pre>';
```